# How to modify NeighborhoodGraph[...] to extract user-designed graph patterns?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given

```
ClearAll[edgeW, n, d, G, system, reducedSystem, sa, wG, scenario, source, sink];
SeedRandom[14];
(* Identify all the pathways from a source to a sink in a  digraph *)
edgeW = Module[{g = #, 
 e = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ 
   FindPath[##, \[Infinity], All]}, 
Transpose[{e, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ # & /@e}]] &; (* by kglr *) 
n = 10;
d = 0.3;
G = RandomGraph[{Round[n], Round[n*(n - 1)*d]}, DirectedEdges -> True];
system = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
reducedSystem =AdjacencyMatrix[G]*system; 
sa = SparseArray[reducedSystem];
wG = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"],DirectedEdges -> True, VertexCapacity -> {i_ :> \[Nu][i]}, VertexSize -> .3, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]; 
scenario = {source = 5, sink = 2};
edgeW[wG, source, sink][[All, 1]] // TableForm
```

This code works fine for the purpose it is designed for. Given source and sink vertices, it extracts all the pathways from source to sink.

I'd like to extend this code in such a way for it to allow me to extract a specific pathway from the graph rather than all the pathways in between source and sink. Conceptually, my question is about identifying various motifs from a given directed graph. I searched for *Motif Community Structure* in MMA but I could not see any. `FindClique` seems to do something like what I am after.

My specific question: Is there any built-in function in MMA to identify *Motif Community Structure* in a given directed graph? Or can the above code be revised to answer my question?

Comment: How would you define a motif community structure?  Could you give an example of a graph and a subgraph you want to extract? perhaps using the [`Subgraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subgraph.html) function

Comment: Jason B: The code given in the question produces a subgraph of all the links from vertex 5 to 2. One can try to extract different subgraphs between any pair of vertices like (6,2), (2,5), (5,8) etc. Let us stick to one of these subgraphs, for example, the one coming from source=6 and sink 1. Then I want to search for a community structure consisting of `Star` graphs assuming that the subgraph of (6,1) has several star graphs with three edges (or 4 vertices). I think for this question it is better to increase `n` to a reasonably large number to increase the possibility of having star graphs.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me what form the output is intended to take. Perhaps ...

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ClearAll[edgeW, n, d, G, system, reducedSystem, sa, wG, scenario, source, 
  sink];
SeedRandom[14];
(*Identify all the pathways from a source to a sink in a digraph*)
edgeW = Module[{g = #, 
     e = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ 
       FindPath[##, ∞, All]}, 
    Transpose[{e, 
      PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ # & /@ e}]] &; (*by kglr*)
n = 10;
d = 0.3;
G = RandomGraph[{Round[n], Round[n*(n - 1)*d]},
   DirectedEdges -> True,
   EdgeStyle -> Thin,
   PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled"];
system = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
reducedSystem = AdjacencyMatrix[G]*system;
sa = SparseArray[reducedSystem];
wG = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"],
   DirectedEdges -> True,
   VertexCapacity -> {i_ :> ν[i]},
   VertexSize -> .3,
   EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"];

paths[source_Integer, sink_Integer] :=
 edgeW[wG, source, sink][[All, 1]]
```

Output

```
Manipulate[
 If[source == sink,
  sink = Max[Mod[source + 1, 1 + VertexCount@G]], 1];
 Module[
  {tab = paths[source, sink]},
  Column[{
    TableForm[tab,
     TableHeadings -> Automatic],
    HighlightGraph[G, tab[[path]],
     GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick",
     ImageSize -> Medium]}]],
 Row[{
   Control[{{source, 5}, Range@VertexCount@G}],
   Spacer[40],
   Control[{{sink, 2}, Range@VertexCount@G}]}],
 Delimiter,
 {{path, 1}, Range@Length@paths[source, sink]},
 ControlType -> SetterBar,
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {source, sink, path}]
```

[image]

Comment: You are right in your question. One of the forms which is of interest is a smallest size star motif (4 vertices with 3 edges). O may need to extend the size of the graph by increasing `n` to a larger number using `Random Graph` built-in function. I think random graphs are more likely to generate smallest star subgraphs.

Comment: `IGraphM` Mathematica compatible software has the `Motif` function. Here are the codes: `mot3 = Graph[#, ImageSize -> 36, VertexSize -> 0.1] & /@ 
   IGData[{"AllDirectedGraphs", 3}];
Grid[{mot3, IGMotifs[g, 3]}\[Transpose], Frame -> All]` This codes solves my general problem but still needs to be improved to input flexible choices of subgraphs.